# Interpretation of a brier score

Tags: modeling, interpretation, model-evaluation, scoring-rules

Suppose that multiple brier scores were computed for two models $A,B$
and the density of the scores plotted as

[image]

Where the average of $A$ is less than $B$

What would the interpretation of this be? Would it just be stated that as the scores are lower on average for $A$ that $A$ is better then $B$ wrt brier scores? Or is there a more meaningful interpretation of the score?

## edit

"*the brier score is a single number, so your question needs to be clarified*"

A brier score is generated for each model over a number of iterations and the
densities of these scores plotted.

Comment: The Brier score is a single number, so your question needs to be clarified.

Comment: @FrankHarrell sorry - i've added some info as to the nature of the density plots.